# Caching pages with query strings in padrino-cache

Tags: caching, will-paginate, padrino

I have Padrino caching working in my app, e.g.

```
get :blog, cache: true do
# do a blog listing
end
```

But when the listings are paginated with `will-paginate`, it can't tell the difference between `/blog` and `/blog?page=2`, and always renders the cached copy of `/blog`. Is there any way to get this to work so that it caches per URL not per route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some [spelunking in the Padrino issues](https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/issues/1729) provides this answer, which seems to work:

```
get :blog, cache: Padrino.config.cache do
  cache_key { request.path_info + '?' + params.slice('page').to_param }
  #do blog listing
end
```

The structure of the Padrino documentation seems to have changed since then, so the PR at the end of that issue no longer seems to be in the current documentation.